# How to get single related object after filter

Tags: python, django, django-orm, django-filter

I got parent-children (1-n) model relation:

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    some_fields = models.IntegerField()

class Child(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent, relatend_name='children')
    first = models.BooleanField()
    second = models.BooleanField()
```

Now I filter parents based on children fields:

```
Parent.objects.filter(children__first=True)
```

This generates the following SQL:

```
SELECT app_parent.*
FROM app_parent
INNER JOIN app_child ON app_parent.id = app_child.parent_id 
WHERE app_child.first = TRUE
```

after that i got all Parent fields **BUT** I want the related Child fields too to get SQL like that:

```
SELECT app_parent.*, app_child.*
FROM app_parent
INNER JOIN app_child ON app_parent.id = app_child.parent_id 
WHERE app_child.first = TRUE
```

and get it via Django ORM. Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

I think I have nice workaround

```
parents = Parent.objects.filter(children__first=True).prefetch_related('children') \
.extra(select={'child_id': '"app_child"."id"'})
for parent in parents:
    parent.child = [child for child in parent.children.all() if child == parent.child_id][0]
```

Comment: Look at `for` loop. There's child attribute assigned aith first child filtered from prefetched children list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related)

```
Parent.objects.filter(children__first=True).prefetch_related('children')
```

Or [`select_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related)

```
Child.objects.filter(first=True).select_related('parent')
```

Comment: I just want one child with first=True

Comment: If for each parent, there are multiple children where `first` is true, then you can only have at a random selection the first row in the returned queryset, which you can get with `Parent.objects.filter(children__first=True)[0]`

Comment: @ArturM I added the `select_related` info for getting one child back but that other comment brings up a good point...

Comment: @Burhan Khalid theres always one `first` child for each parent and I need get all parents with the one child for each.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the [fetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) method for that and do the lookup the other way around unfortunately.

In this case it should be something like this:

```
first_children = Child.objects.filter(first=True).select_related('parent')
parents = [c.parent for c in first_children]
```

Comment: I use this python solution atm (btw I think it should be select_related)

Comment: Yes... I got it confused with prefetch_related, you are right :)